Ringe-LWE Based Fully Homomorphic Encryption Schemes and the Expansion Factor $\delta_R$ for Noise Estimation
In this paper on page 3 the term expansion factor of R is introduced and defined as
$$\delta_R = \max \left\{\frac{||a \cdot b||}{||a|| \cdot ||b||} \;\Bigg| \; a,b \in R \right\}$$
With $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$ being a ring of polynomials with $f(x) = x^n +1$ and $||\cdot||$ is the infinity norm. In another source I have read that "it is well known that"
$$\delta_R=n$$
I struggle to find good resources discussing the reasons on this fact and I would also love to find more information on noise estimation for the proofs of correct encryption for FHEs.
My questions therefore are

How is the expansion factor $\delta_R$ mathematically justified (and therefore $=n$)?
Do you know good resources to further read on this concept?
On a further note, do you also know good resources which discuss noise estimations in detail for FHEs like BFV?


The high-level idea here is that we want a way to quantify noise that works well with typical noise that occurs in lattice-based cryptography.
These noise expressions typically involve sums and products of random polynomials, so our way of quantifying noise should behave well with respect to sums and products of random polynomials.
The standard $\ell_\infty$ norm behaves ok with respect to (polynomial) addition.
As an example, as it is a norm, we get that for any error polynomials $e_i(x)$ that
$$
\lVert \sum_{i = 1}^k e_i(x)\rVert \leq \sum_{i = 1}^k \lVert e_i(x)\rVert.
$$
Here, I say "ok" because this bound is mildly loose for the common case of $e_i(x)$ i.i.d. Gaussians (say of standard deviation $\sigma$).
The above bound suffices to get high-probability tail bounds on $E = \lVert\sum_{i = 1}^k e_i(x)\rVert$ of the form
$$
\Pr[E > \sigma t\sqrt{\log n}]\leq \exp(-O(t^2)),
$$
while one can (with better analysis) prove that
$$
\Pr[E > \sigma \sqrt{t\log n}] \leq \exp(-O(t^2)).
$$
This is to say that appealing to the "worst-case" bound loses a multiplicative factor $\sqrt{t}$, compared to a tighter (but Gaussian specific) "average-case" bound, that one may heuristically extend to other concentrated distributions (here, it provably extends to what are called sub-Gaussian distributions, but some authors apply it to other less concentrated distributions).
What about (polynomial) products?
it would be nice to write
$$
\lVert e_0(x)\ast e_1(x)\rVert \leq \lVert e_0(x)\lVert \rVert e_1(x)\rVert,
$$
but this is not true. Instead, we need to introduce some "fudge factor" (typically written $\delta_R$, the ring expansion factor) such that it is true.
To get an expression for this, we can write
$$
\delta_R :=\sup_{f, g}\frac{\lVert f(x)\ast g(x)\rVert}{\lVert f(x)\rVert\lVert g(x)\rVert}.
$$
Then, for any particular $e_0, e_1$, we have that
$$
\lVert e_0(x)\ast e_1(x)\rVert = \lVert e_0(x)\rVert \lVert e_0(x)\rVert\frac{\lVert e_0(x)\ast e_1(x)\rVert}{\lVert e_0(x)\rVert \lVert e_1(x)\rVert} \leq \lVert e_0(x)\rVert\lVert e_1(x)\rVert \sup_{e_0, e_1}\frac{\lVert e_0(x)\ast e_1(x)\rVert}{\lVert e_0(x)\rVert \lVert e_1(x)\rVert} = \delta_R \lVert e_0(x)\rVert\lVert e_1(x)\rVert,
$$
e.g. $\delta_R$ is precisely the "fudge-factor" such that the norm of the product is the product of the norms (similarly to sums).
Bounding $\delta_R$ is pretty naive.
Note that each coordinate of $f(x)\ast g(x)\bmod x^n+1$ is of the sum of products of coordinates of $f$ and $g$ (and perhaps a sign $\epsilon\in\{\pm 1\}$).
As an example (this is true for all other coordinates though), one can check that the constant term of $f\ast g\bmod x^n+1$ is of the form
$$
f_0g_1 - f_1g_{n-1} - f_2g_{n-2}-\dots.
$$
One can easily upper bound this by $n\lVert f(x)\rVert \lVert g(x)\rVert$.
Each coordinate of $f(x)\ast g(x)$ may be upper-bounded by this quantity, so we get that
$$
\lVert f(x)\ast g(x)\bmod x^n+1\rVert \leq n\lVert f(x)\rVert \lVert g(x)\rVert.
$$
Note that people typically don't use this bound for $\delta_R$ though.
It is "worst-case" (similarly to the above bound for additions).
People often (heuristically) appeal to the "average-case" bound that $\delta_R = 2\sqrt{n}$.
This is not a provable statement, but can be experimentally observed in certain settings (see for example section 6.1 of this).
As for noise estimation for BFV, there are various things people do.
The provable results one gets are not good, so instead people typically apply heuristic (but not provable) arguments, and validate experimentally that the noise is of the size the heuristics predict.
See for example this or this.
I have some work in progress regarding improving the provable results one can get. I might update this answer once I finally make it public.
